# Fluent Bit output to Splunk on Windows

Tags: windows, fluent-bit

I tried following command to send logs to Splunk

```
fluent-bit -i dummy -o splunk -p host=10.16.0.41 -p port=8088 -p tls=off -p tls.verify=off -p splunk_token=my_splunk_token_value -m '*'
```

It works with Mac OS ***but not working when it runs on Windows***.
On Windows, it gives following error

```
[error] [io] connection #680 failed to: 10.16.0.41:8088
[debug] [upstream] connection #680 failed to 10.16.0.41:8088
[debug] [retry] new retry created for task_id=0 attempts=1
[ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '7624-1609745347.351439100.flb', retry in 7 seconds: task_id=0, input=dummy.0 > output=splunk.0
```

I can *telnet* to that port in Windows machine as well

```
telnet 10.16.0.41 8088
```

I am using ***td-agent-bit-1.6.9-win64.zip*** as in the [documentation](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/installation/windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with fluent-bit versions 1.6.8 & 1.6.9 Windows executables.
Issue is described in [GitHub issues](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/2923) as well. Fix has been added in 1.6.10 version.

As I got to know, issue was ***"Windows socket interface don't handle 'errno' properly***"